# How can I reference an entity field in a template file?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

I am trying to theme the node add/edit form for a custom content type (for example, *Album*). I implemented `hook_form_alter()` in the theme.

```php
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case "node_album_form":
      $form['#theme'] = ['node_album_edit_form'];
      break;
  }
}
```

That correctly intercepts the node add/edit form and passes it to my theme hook which also finds the correct template.

```php
function mytheme_theme() {
  return [
    'node_album_form' => [
      'template' => 'node_album_edit_form',
      'path' => \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getPath() . '/scss/templates/album',
      'render element' => 'form'
    ],
  ];
}
```

In *node_album_edit_form.html.twig*, I can confirm that changes there alter only the album add/edit form and that I can remove elements with `{{ form|without('advanced', 'footer', 'actions') }}`, for example.

What I cannot do is placing the form fields where I want them because I'm not using the right reference to the field.

```html
<div class='myfancydiv album-title-field'>{{ field_album_title }}</div>
<div class='myfancydiv album-artist-field'>{{ field_artist }}</div>
```

I tried any of the following, but they didn't work.

- `{{ field_album_title }}`
- `{{ form.field_album_title }}`
- `{{ album_title }}`

How can I reference an entity field in a template file?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I'm not able to get this to work, trying numerous permutations of this to confirm. Do you have any documentation / reference to where this is used? I suspect that the issue here is how my form_alter hook is interacting with the theme hook but most of the documentation I have found only refers to custom forms.

Answer (score 0):

Change your hook_theme code to:

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  return [
    'node_album_edit_form' => [
      'path' => \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getPath() . '/scss/templates/album',
      'render element' => 'form'
    ],
  ];
}
```

and in your template file

```
{{ form.field_album_title }}
```